# BeatifulSoup find result with condition

Tags: python, soap, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How to parse some code with condition? I have soap response and i need to print only component_id which contains type=1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetTerritoriesHierarhyResponse
            xmlns="http://parsec.ru/Parsec3IntergationService">
            <GetTerritoriesHierarhyResult>
                <Territory xsi:type="TerritoryWithComponent">
                    <ID>13c80b2d-d9d3-47cd-9c11-f80597b61e74</ID>
                    <TYPE>0</TYPE>
                    <NAME>OFFLINE</NAME>
                    <PARENT_ID>88ef0e32-3b6f-467c-a0ec-0733317f6757</PARENT_ID>
                    <COMPONENT_ID>13c80b2d-d9d3-47cd-9c11-f80597b61e74</COMPONENT_ID>
                    <FEATURE_MASK>0</FEATURE_MASK>
                </Territory>
                K>0</FEATURE_MASK>
                </Territory>
<Territory xsi:type="TerritoryWithComponent">
                    <ID>7d432ebb-6199-44c5-b67b-4671718e6e3c</ID>
                    <TYPE>1</TYPE>
                    <NAME>PREO</NAME>
                    <PARENT_ID>88ef0e32-3b6f-467c-a0ec-0733317f6757</PARENT_ID>
                    <COMPONENT_ID>7d432ebb-6199-44c5-b67b-4671718e6e3c</COMPONENT_ID>
                    <FEATURE_MASK>0</FEATURE_MASK>
                </Territory>
            </GetTerritoriesHierarhyResult>
        </GetTerritoriesHierarhyResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have some code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')
for i in soup.find_all('Territory'):
  print(i.text)
```

response

```
13c80b2d-d9d3-47cd-9c11-f80597b61e740OFFLINE88ef0e32-3b6f-467c-a0ec-0733317f675713c80b2d-d9d3-47cd-9c11-f80597b61e740
7d432ebb-6199-44c5-b67b-4671718e6e3c0PREO88ef0e32-3b6f-467c-a0ec-0733317f67577d432ebb-6199-44c5-b67b-4671718e6e3c0
```

I think i need something like

```
for i in soup.find_all('Territory'):
  if type = 1 print component_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could iterate and check as you suggest with the `if` statement:

**Given:**

```
xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetTerritoriesHierarhyResponse
            xmlns="http://parsec.ru/Parsec3IntergationService">
            <GetTerritoriesHierarhyResult>
                <Territory xsi:type="TerritoryWithComponent">
                    <ID>13c80b2d-d9d3-47cd-9c11-f80597b61e74</ID>
                    <TYPE>0</TYPE>
                    <NAME>OFFLINE</NAME>
                    <PARENT_ID>88ef0e32-3b6f-467c-a0ec-0733317f6757</PARENT_ID>
                    <COMPONENT_ID>13c80b2d-d9d3-47cd-9c11-f80597b61e74</COMPONENT_ID>
                    <FEATURE_MASK>0</FEATURE_MASK>
                </Territory>
                K>0</FEATURE_MASK>
                </Territory>
<Territory xsi:type="TerritoryWithComponent">
                    <ID>7d432ebb-6199-44c5-b67b-4671718e6e3c</ID>
                    <TYPE>1</TYPE>
                    <NAME>PREO</NAME>
                    <PARENT_ID>88ef0e32-3b6f-467c-a0ec-0733317f6757</PARENT_ID>
                    <COMPONENT_ID>7d432ebb-6199-44c5-b67b-4671718e6e3c</COMPONENT_ID>
                    <FEATURE_MASK>0</FEATURE_MASK>
                </Territory>
            </GetTerritoriesHierarhyResult>
        </GetTerritoriesHierarhyResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'''
```

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')
for i in soup.find_all('Territory'):
  if i.select('TYPE')[0].text == '1':
      print (i.select('COMPONENT_ID')[0].text)
```

Or

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')
for i in soup.find_all('TYPE', text='1'):
    print (i.parent.find('COMPONENT_ID').text)
```

**Output:**

```
7d432ebb-6199-44c5-b67b-4671718e6e3c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:has` and `:contains` pseudo class with bs4 4.7.1 to test if present. You will get an empty list if not. Specify `xml` for parser. It is more succinct to read I think.

Lines:

```
soup = bs(xml, 'xml')
results = [item.select_one('COMPONENT_ID').text for item in soup.select('Territory:has(TYPE:contains("1"))')]
print(results)
```

Full:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

xml = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetTerritoriesHierarhyResponse
            xmlns="http://parsec.ru/Parsec3IntergationService">
            <GetTerritoriesHierarhyResult>
                <Territory xsi:type="TerritoryWithComponent">
                    <ID>13c80b2d-d9d3-47cd-9c11-f80597b61e74</ID>
                    <TYPE>0</TYPE>
                    <NAME>OFFLINE</NAME>
                    <PARENT_ID>88ef0e32-3b6f-467c-a0ec-0733317f6757</PARENT_ID>
                    <COMPONENT_ID>13c80b2d-d9d3-47cd-9c11-f80597b61e74</COMPONENT_ID>
                    <FEATURE_MASK>0</FEATURE_MASK>
                </Territory>
                K>0</FEATURE_MASK>
                </Territory>
                <Territory xsi:type="TerritoryWithComponent">
                    <ID>7d432ebb-6199-44c5-b67b-4671718e6e3c</ID>
                    <TYPE>1</TYPE>
                    <NAME>PREO</NAME>
                    <PARENT_ID>88ef0e32-3b6f-467c-a0ec-0733317f6757</PARENT_ID>
                    <COMPONENT_ID>7d432ebb-6199-44c5-b67b-4671718e6e3c</COMPONENT_ID>
                    <FEATURE_MASK>0</FEATURE_MASK>
                </Territory>
            </GetTerritoriesHierarhyResult>
        </GetTerritoriesHierarhyResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'''

soup = bs(xml, 'xml')
results = [item.select_one('COMPONENT_ID').text for item in soup.select('Territory:has(TYPE:contains("1"))')]
print(results)
```